# Linux icon appearing in rEFind even after uninstalling Linux

Tags: boot, bootloader, refind

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my mac.and I uninstalled it and but after that when I boot up using rEFind. it shows me an Linux icon saying that boot Linux from whole disk space.how can I get rid of it?.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want:

- In `refind.conf`, uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that it does *not* include the `hdbios` option. This will also have the effect of removing any other BIOS-mode boot options from the menu (at least for your internal disk), so if you're dual-booting Windows, this option may be undesirable.
- In `refind.conf`, use the `dont_scan_volumes` option, and specify any unique subset of the description you want to remove, such as `dont_scan_volumes "whole disk"`, assuming no other entry you care about includes the string "whole disk".
- Using a Linux emergency disk, wipe GRUB from the MBR of the hard disk by doing something like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=440 count=1`. ***This command is potentially quite dangerous!*** If you get any of the options wrong, you could seriously damage your partition table or even permanently destroy data on your hard disk. This command should take a fraction of a second to execute. Also, you must ***NOT*** issue the equivalent of this command in OS X, since OS X's version of `dd` doesn't let you specify partial-sector block sizes (`bs=440`).

If you opt to edit `refind.conf`, you must locate it. If your rEFInd installation is an old one or if you used the option to install it to your OS X root (`/`) partition, it will be `/EFI/refind/refind.conf`. If your rEFInd installation is newer, it's more likely to be in that directory on your ESP, which you'll need to mount:

```
mkdir /Volumes/ESP
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP
```

`refind.conf` will then probably be at `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind/refind.conf`.